# SVN diff users changes

Tags: svn

I use the command

```
svn diff -r from_verno:to_verno svn_url --summarize
```

to get the details. It shows the result,

```
A  file_path
```

I want to show the last author who checked in the source. Which option to use for the command to get that information?

Answer (score 2):

If you type

```
svn log -q -r from_verno:to_verno SVN_URL_OR_FILENAME
```

you get a short list of all the commits between these two revisions.

If you just want the newest commit in the list, make that

```
svn log -q -r from_verno:to_verno SVN_URL_OR_FILENAME | head -2 | tail -1
```

To extract just the username from that, use

```
svn log -q -r from_verno:to_verno SVN_URL_OR_FILENAME | head -2 | tail -1 | cut -d '|' -f2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only get the information about the author for a single revision (via svn log -r Revision) not for a diff, cause in the diff you are diffing two or more revsions which might be created by different author.

Comment: Which means the author of the last change in the repository? svn log -r HEAD --limit 1 Or from the diff ? From diff it is not possible..